# "Autodesk.Viewing.WebVR" extension does not work on Mirage Solo

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to use Forge viewer on Mirage Solo.
But I still not get correct behavior.
Has anyone succeeded in this integration?

1. chrome:flags -> WebVR -> true
2. access to below app.

http://forge-test-socket.herokuapp.com/viewer?path=resources/models/seat/seat.svf&extIds=Autodesk.Viewing.WebVR

or

https://www.vrok.it/v2
and connect session.

3.push "Enable VR mode" button

4.The screen change to black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webVR extension officially supports Google cardboard and daydream.  Vive and Oculus headsets were unofficially supported.  Mirage Solo headset is also not officially supported (unfortunately).